# programmatically set "Layout to right of" property in android

Tags: android

I want to set property "Layout to right of" of control at runtime in android. Actually I want to adjust controls when screen changes orientation.

Comment: The preferred way to "adjust controls when screen changes orientation" is to use two separate layout XML files, one for portrait (typically in `res/layout/`) and one for landscape (typically in `res/layout-land/`).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, view.getId());
```

Comment: @Prasad You can remove it with params.removeRule( RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF );

Comment: `removeRule(..)` is available from API 17. [for < API 17](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15630905/2820534)

Answer (score 5):

If you define a new `LayoutParams`, you lose other rules.

So if you just want to change or add a rule, do this:

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, targetView.getId());
 view.setLayoutParams(params);
```