# Programmatically change RelativeLayout toRightOf to toLeftOf

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

i'm making chat app. I want to put timestamp besides the chat bubble. The messages will be aligned left (for received) and right (for sent).

So, I'm looking for a way to change `toLeftOf` to `toRightOf`. For now, it looks like this:

[image: Timestamp wrongly aligned]

Here's my XML code for each message (I have `ArrayAdapter` that handle this)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bubble"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeStamp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bubble" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I googling around and found this, but doesn't work:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
if(isReceivedMessage){
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.bubble);
}
else{
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.bubble);
}
timeStampTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rewrite**
Remove the attribute `layout_toRightOf` from the current TextView, then create two different LayoutParams: one for `toRightOf` and one for `toLeftOf`. You can switch the parameters depending on your needs.

An alternative is to use a custom adapter with two layouts. This approach should be faster since you aren't re-arranging the layout at run-time but maintaining two separate lists of "Reply" and "Send" layouts in the view recycler.

(As a note, API 17 introduced [`removeRule()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#removeRule%28int%29) but this won't help just yet.)

Comment: I can't seem to find the `removeRule()` method. Is that built-in or we must make first?

Comment: Sorry, it was just [added in API 17](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#removeRule%28int%29)... Which doesn't help for current devices. But I still believe the multiple layout approach is best.

Comment: Wait, have you tried using two different LayoutParams? And switching them with `tv.setLayoutParams(leftParams)`?

Comment: Yeah, multiple layout sounds easy, I will use it for last resort if I can't find any way. Thanks

Comment: If you need it here is [a general explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13316605/1267661) of how to use multiple layouts in a custom adapter, just ask if you want more specific advice.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I just decided to put two layout. It works now.

Comment: addRule(RelativeLayout.[Required rule], 0) can be used in place of removeRule() to support older API levels.

Answer (score 11):

Try this to remove the **toRightOf** and **toLeftOf** property from any view.I am removing these properties from textview.

```
    TextView header2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_header_shoppinglist);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParams2=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)header2.getLayoutParams();
        mLayoutParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,0);
        mLayoutParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,0);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have solved this with the answer above, but next time i will try this

Answer (score 0):

Please used below Code.

```
RelativeLayout wrapper = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
if(isReceivedMessage){
    wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
}
else{
    wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

Comment: That code is to align the chat bubble right? I already did that

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a way to change the timestamp position. I already have the code that align the bubble

Comment: please remove all rules above you have posted. just put my code display as per you image. just put my code. both align right and both align left.